# no overload for method 'METHOD' takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, winforms, overloading

I have 3 methods.

1 method holding the value of 3000
1 method holding the value of 0.13

and I have created another method that I want to multiply these two figures together.

```
public override int FishPerTank()
{                
    return 3000;                
}

public override double WeightOut(double weightOut, double weightIn)
{
    return 0.13;
}

public override int HowMuchTheFishWeighOutKG()
{
    return (FishPerTank() * WeightOut());
}
```

I am receiving the syntax error on the WeightOut here:

```
public override int HowMuchTheFishWeighOutKG()
{
    return (FishPerTank() * WeightOut());
}
```

Comment: @ClaudioRedi is correct. Also, watch that you are multiplying by a double (WeightOut), but then returning an integer. You'll lose the decimal places (not sure if that is your desired result).

Comment: Out of curiosity....why are you using override.  Do these specific methods exist in some base class as virtual methods such that they need to be overridden with custom versions for your class?

Comment: @JasonDown - he won't get to the point of losing precision. He'll get a compile error because there is no implicit conversion from double to int.

Comment: @hatchet: Yes you're right... the implicit conversion exists the other way around. Time for some coffee I think...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`WeightOut` expect 2 parameters and you're not providing them

Answer (score 5):

`WeightOut(double weightOut, double weightIn)` is declared with two parameters and you're calling it with none. Hence the error.

Answer (score 5):

```
WeightOut()
```

expects two parameters. But why ? You don't use them.

Rewrite your method without the 2 parameters

```
public double WeightOut()
{
   return 0.13;
}
```

Comment: I use the 2 parameters in my base class as it does the calculation there.

Comment: In that case you had to use the two parameters, and when you call the method you have to pass them. Also, if you want to reuse the code of your base class you'll have to call it `base.WeightOut(parameter1, parameter2)`.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to change

```
public override double WeightOut(double weightOut, double weightIn)
{
    return 0.13;
}
```

to

```
public override double WeightOut()
{
    return 0.13;
}
```

as you aren't using the parameters.

also why the override?  May need to remove that if removing the parameters causes another syntax error, or fix it in the base class as well.